# How to prove $f(x,y)\ge 0$ in $[0,1]^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

I had to prove the following in my research, and I wanted to ensure that my proof was clean (it appeared to me to be so).

I have a two-dimensional function $f(x,y)$ defined over the domain $[0,1]^2$. I need to prove this function is non-negative over the domain. I proved three things separately.

1. $f(0,0)=0$.
2. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\ge 0$ $\forall y$.
3. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\ge 0$ $\forall x$.

Are these three sufficient to prove $f(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in the domain?

Comment: Yes. What else? And of course, better try it first...

Comment: When is this due?

Comment: @Did: Not a homework problem. Just thinking aloud.

Comment: Oh, you met this question by chance, just thinking by yourself? But you have no idea of the context? Sorry but these two circumstances do not go together...

Comment: @Did: I encountered this in my research, and I do not have a formal analysis background.

Comment: All these circumstances, if true, should be in the question since they might help to explain its rather bizarre, from a mathematician's point of view, content.

Comment: @Did: or, you could avoid being nasty.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Archu: please don't let the unfriendliness scare you. This site is not very welcoming, but if you survive the initial shock, it can be a very useful resource.

Comment: @Did: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: Much better now. But you allude to a proof that you want to see checked: thus, again, you need to include it in your post. (But don't let the unfriendliness scare you...)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Mean value theorem twice.